# CSS styling for checkbox with specific name in Angular

Tags: css, angular

If I have three checkboxes in Angular template, like this:

```
  <mat-checkbox fxFlexFill formControlName="first">  First  </mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox fxFlexFill formControlName="second"> Second </mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox fxFlexFill formControlName="third">  Third  </mat-checkbox>
```

What would be the correct approach for adding space before the first one, without having to change the template?

I.e. I know I can add a class to the first one, but it feels semantically wrong (perhaps I am wrong of course, but I have a feeling I should be able to do this solely with css), so I was wondering if it was possible to do something similar to inputs, i.e.:

```
// css
mat-checkbox[name="first"] {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css, change `name="first"` to `formControlName="first"` as in your html there is no attribute called **name** but **formControlName**.

```css
mat-checkbox[formControlName="first"] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<mat-checkbox fxFlexFill formControlName="first"> First </mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox fxFlexFill formControlName="second"> Second </mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox fxFlexFill formControlName="third"> Third </mat-checkbox>
```